# share on facebook with query string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, facebook, hyperlink

I have the following problem I can't find a proper solution for and would be very graceful for any advice.

On my website, I provide a sharing option for facebook:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=www.mypage.de&title=MyPage" target="_blank">Jetzt teilen</a>
```

I use open graph to add meta information for the FB crawler

```
<meta property="og:url"         content="http://www.mypage.de" />
<meta property="og:type"        content="website" />
<meta property='og:title'       content='MyPage'>
<meta property='og:description' content='Viele tolle Sachen'>
<meta property='og:image'       content='http://www.mypage.de/image.jpg'>
```

This works fine so far. The user will see Image, description and Titel.

But as I want to add individual information on each shared link, I need to add a query string that is shared ( ?queryString=qwe123 ). So I change the URL:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=www.mypage.de%3FqueryString%3Dqwe123&title=MyPage" target="_blank">Jetzt teilen</a>
```

But when the user now clicks the link, he wont see the description and image of the page any more (the linking works fine anyway). I cant let FB crawl every possible query-string because each user has an individual one.

Anyone has a good idea?

P.S. I know that share.php is deprecated, but don't know whats the actual way to share without using an App_ID from FB.

P.P.S. I use angular 1.4 if that is of any importance

Comment: If you want to pass parameters to your site via query string, then your og:url value must contain those parameters as well.

Comment: the problem is, that this string will differ from user to user and FB will not crawl all of them (if they crawl pages with query strings at all). Furthermore, the DOM is generated before the query string ist loaded

Comment: The sharer.php/Share dialog only takes the URL to share as parameter, everything else is ignored. If you still want to specify other parameters at run-time, then you can use the Feed dialog.

Comment: okay, I solved this now by using https://github.com/720kb/angular-socialshare.
This is a nice little framework where you can set the facebook sharing as feed and this works fine with query strings. Also supports a bunch of other social plugins and is easy to use.